# Delay from Salesforce.com in querying records, Informatica

Tags: data-loader, informatica

We are trying to insert records into salesforce org through informatica

Batch Size = 200

no of records of records inserted  4000 to  50,000

Informatica process shows that insertion is completed. But when we try to query records through Informatica for through SOQL Explorer we get like 50% of records in query and 
if we try to query those records again after 10 or 15 mins. we get all the records which are inserted. [means it takes sometime to make inserted records available for query]

wanted to check if there is any way to get around this problem. 
Did this(similar behavior) happened to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like informatica is using the bulk API. This doesn't actually create the records as they're being uploaded like the non-bulk SOAP and REST APIs do but places them into a queue where salesforce processes them asynchronously.

Take a look at the informatica options to see if you can fall back to the SOAP API if this is a serious issue; it will be slower but when it's "done" uploading it really will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes we are using bulk API, I will try to go back to SOAP API.  salesforce support mentioned us something about parallel and serial mode.   is it like Buik API = parallel mode and SOAP API = serial mode.